# Issue with slipstreaming updates on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, update, dism

So I've been trying to slipstream updates on my Windows Server 2016 Datacenter edition (1607), as I often deploy test servers and wanted to have an ISO with the updates baked-in to accelerate the process.

Pretty much every guide I can get my hands on tells me to do the same thing, so here are the commands I am using.

```
Mount-DiskImage C:\slipstream_updates\iso\base_server_2016_datacenter\SW_DVD9_Win_Svr_STD_Core_and_DataCtr_Core_2016_64Bit_English_-2_MLF_X21-22843.ISO

robocopy /s /e E:\ C:\slipstream_updates\copied_base_iso_files

Dismount-DiskImage C:\slipstream_updates\iso\base_server_2016_datacenter\SW_DVD9_Win_Svr_STD_Core_and_DataCtr_Core_2016_64Bit_English_-2_MLF_X21-22843.ISO

Set-ItemProperty C:\slipstream_updates\copied_base_iso_files\sources\install.wim -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false

dism.exe /mount-wim /wimfile:"C:\slipstream_updates\copied_base_iso_files\sources\install.wim" /mountdir:"C:\slipstream_updates\wim_mountpoint" /index:1

dism.exe /image:"C:\slipstream_updates\wim_mountpoint" /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\slipstream_updates\cumulative_update_files\august\ssu"

dism /image:"C:\slipstream_updates\wim_mountpoint" /cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase

dism /unmount-image /mountdir:"C:\slipstream_updates\wim_mountpoint" /commit

cd "C:\slipstream_updates\copied_base_iso_files\"; & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe'-bootdata:"2#p0,e,bboot\Etfsboot.com#pEF,e,befi\Microsoft\boot\Efisys.bin" -u1 -udfver102 C:\slipstream_updates\copied_base_iso_files C:\slipstream_updates\iso\WindowsServer2016_SSU_KB4132216.iso
```

In the previous example, I tried to slipstream KB4132214 which is the SSU required to install further Cumulative Updates from the Microsoft Catalog according to the information page. After this, I would do the same procedure, using the newly created ISO to try and add KB4343887 (August Cumulative Updates) and create a separate ISO file.

But then after installing a new machine with the newly created ISO, the updates simply don't show up. Not in the Installed Updates panel (none of the updates show up, not even KB4132216 that was installed at first), not by running Get-Hotfix, and running "winver" tells me it is still "Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.0)".

While creating the ISO files, every command finished successfully, and looking at the created ISO files, I see the size of that file increase between steps, so I'm assuming files are indeed getting copied in there.

I have tried using the same process to slipstream a different Cumulative update, KB4103720 which is usually the first that the server tried to fetch from Windows Update upon launching "Check for Updates" on a newly installed server straight from the base ISO, but to no avail.

Am I missing something? Am I possibly doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try remounting the updated WIM and listing the installed packages to confirm they are present.

Comment: It shows them as "installed". https://pastebin.com/VGfWfkYE

Comment: To clarify, it shows them as "installed" when listing the packages by running /Get-Packages from the mounted WIM image.

When attempting a "Check for Updates" on a newly installed system from this ISO, it still tries to download and install KB4132216 and KB4103720, as if they were not present at all.

Comment: I have seen some updates magically disappearing after /startcomponentcleanup /resetbase on a live image. There was a difference whren running /online /get-packages - the status was 'installed' before cleanup, and have disappeared from the list afterwards. I don't know why, but that didn't happen on every update.

Comment: don't waste your time with updating a WIM all over again. Use setupcomplete.cmd to install the updates. In the script install first the last SSU and next the last Cumulative Update, in last step do the reboot. When you updates come out, replace the old MSU with new ones.